# Android Room Library Select query fails on assertion __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();

Tags: java, android

I am doing Notes application for Android in Java. I am trying to add support to have one image for every edit text view. the relevant code goes like this:

```
@Fts4
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    public int rowid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "contents")
    public String contents;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "photoPath")
    public String photoPath;

}
```

the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Query("INSERT INTO notes (contents, photoPath) VALUES ('new note', '.')")
    void create();

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET photoPath = :path where rowid = :id ")
    void updatePhotoPath(String path, int id);

    @Query("SELECT *, rowid from notes; ")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT *, rowid from notes WHERE contents MATCH :creteria")
    List<Note> fetchNotes(String creteria);

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET contents = :contents WHERE rowid = :id")
    void save(String contents, int id);

    @Query("DELETE from notes WHERE rowid = :id")
    void delete(int id);
}
```

and the failing code of the adaptor to the recycler view that tries to make a call to get all notes.

```
public void reload() {
        notes = MainActivity.database.NoteDao().getAllNotes();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

that was part of adaptor code called by main activity from inside onResume.

and the falling error log contains the following:

```
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:275)
at com.sultanraja.notes.NoteDao_Impl.getAllNotes(NoteDao_Impl.java:138)
at com.sultanraja.notes.NotesAdapter.reload(NotesAdapter.java:69)
at com.sultanraja.notes.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:77)
```

the code of which is:

```
public void assertNotSuspendingTransaction() {
        if (!inTransaction() && mSuspendingTransactionId.get() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot access database on a different coroutine"
                    + " context inherited from a suspending transaction.");
        }
    }
```

so what is a coroutine and why this did not happen before I added the photoPath String to the database?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add column in your database like this. You need to migrate (ALTER TABLE):

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE notes"
                + " ADD COLUMN photoPath STRING NOT NULL");
    }
   };

Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDb.class, "database-name")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3).build();
```

Comment: thanks, but now I am falling on: 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: virtual tables may not be altered (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN photoPath STRING NOT NULL

Comment: Did you change migration value? Follow this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Comment: I did eventually use fallbackToDestructiveMigration. i.e erased the tiny db I had to skip this miss. and it works. my application is almost ready for pulish.  needs testing only.